# Salt-Stack copy file python API from salt master to specific minion

Tags: saltstack

I am using CentOS6.5. I can successfully copy a file from master to a minion with id=minionId by running the following command on the master:

```
salt minionId cp.get_file salt://fileInMaster.txt /home/johnDoe/fileNowInMinion.txt ##run on master
```

If I have to accomplish the exact same thing using python how do I do it? Following [this link](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html) all I find is a way to copy a file from master to minion by running a script on the minion. I want to run a python script on master that copies a file from master to a specific minion with given Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Python client API, or install and run salt-api which exposes a REST API.  I'll detail the Python client API: http://salt.readthedocs.org/en/v2014.1.13/ref/clients/index.html

Script totin.py, copies /srv/salt/vim/vimrc.local to tin:/tmp/vimrc.local

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import salt.client

minion = 'tin'
source = 'salt://vim/vimrc.local'
target = '/tmp/vimrc.local'

local = salt.client.LocalClient()
ret = local.cmd('tin', 'cp.get_file', [source, target])
print json.dumps(ret, indent=2)
```

Test:

```
$ sudo python totin.py 
{
  "tin": "/tmp/vimrc.local"
}
```

Verify:

```
$ sudo salt tin cmd.run 'ls -l /tmp/vimrc.local'
tin:
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 652 Dec  4 20:45 /tmp/vimrc.local
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like what I wanted. I am in the process of trying this. Will let you know what happens.

Comment: How goes the battle @TheGovernor?

Comment: Finally got to trying it. Works like charm thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your salt command in python using pexpect or some shell invocation module (os.system, subprocess.call, etc.)

Comment: I don't want to shell out to another process. Thanks though.